# C# Visible windows but I don't want them to show up in Alt+Tab?

Tags: c#

I have a program I'm working that is a ticker across the bottom of the screen. All that functionality is fine, but I've noticed that when I hit Alt+Tab I see it in the list. I already have ShowInTaskbar set to false, but I don't want my program to appear in this list. Is there a property I'm forgetting about or a WinAPI call I can make to keep my app from showing up in Windows Alt+Tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this will help...

[Best way to hide a window from the Alt-Tab program switcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested the code, but a little Googling led me to [this](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic25555.aspx):

```
private static uint WS_POPUP            = 0x80000000;
private static uint WS_EX_TOPMOST       = 0x00000008;
private static uint WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW    = 0x00000080;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style = unchecked((int) WS_POPUP);
        cp.ExStyle = (int) WS_EX_TOPMOST + (int) WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;

        // Set location
        cp.X = 100;
        cp.Y = 100;

        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. After adding that code, when I call the Show method, it says invalid parameters. The problem seems to be when you set cp.ExStyle, I commented that line out and the program ran, even though the window was still visible in Alt+Tab

Comment: Well bummer! Sorry about that. :(

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the window style to be a Toolbox window aswell as ShowInTaskbar to false. Just change the BorderStyle of the form to be FixedToolWindow or SizeableToolWindow. See [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) for more details.

Comment: This does not work.  I just tried it with Windows Forms and WPF, and both times the window still showed up in the ALT+TAB view.

Comment: I assume you haven't set "ShowInTaskbar" to false?

Comment: The OP had already done this hence why I never mentioned it, updated though for clarity.

Comment: Yes, I did not set the ShowInTaskbar to false.  After setting it to false, it does work.  Much better option than doing the Windows API calls.

Comment: In addition to the fact it doesn't work, I already have my FormBorderStyle set to None, so this approach cannot be taken. The window is customed designed with images and is actually made to look like an extension to a parent window (which I also don't want to show up in Alt+Tab).

Comment: @Corey, it would have helped if you explained this in your question....if that is the case you will have to use the Windows API calls to do this.

Comment: setting "ShowInTaskbar" to false when using the "None" in FormBorderstyle doesn't work. I am using Windows 8 and I believe this is already tested in Windows 7.