# C# Application Not starting minimizied

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system-tray

I've built a C# app that I want to start just in the notification area. The icon appears when it is run, and it does not appear in the task bar (due to ShowInTaskbar = false & WindowState = Minimized). However when it first runs I can still alt-tab to it. Is there anyway to prevent this behaviour? Or have I missed a setting somewhere?

Thanks,
Psy

Comment: Since the accepted answer links to a WPF question, I'm assuming this question is WPF as well, even though it didn't specify. Adding tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher).

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is correct behaviour, Alt+Tab will restore minimized windows.

It looks like you want a tray application, but be a bit more specific.