# How to remove WPF application from Flip3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, aero, flip3d

How can I make a WPF window that will never appear in the Flip3d  (Winkey+Tab) dialog?

Comment: I do not believe you can.  If the process is running and it has a form/window that the user can see, one would hope Microsoft wouldn't allow this, otherwise it would be to easy to write malware.

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate question.  That is assuming that Alt-Tab and Win-Tab use the same window styles behind the scenes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher

Comment: That will remove from Alt+Tab dialog but not worked for flip 3d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;
namespace NoFlip3D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);
        [Flags]
        public enum DwmWindowAttribute
        {
            NCRenderingEnabled = 1,
            NCRenderingPolicy,
            TransitionsForceDisabled,
            AllowNCPaint,
            CaptionButtonBounds,
            NonClientRtlLayout,
            ForceIconicRepresentation,
            Flip3DPolicy,
            ExtendedFrameBounds,
            HasIconicBitmap,
            DisallowPeek,
            ExcludedFromPeek,
            Last
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DwmNCRenderingPolicy
        {
            UseWindowStyle,
            Disabled,
            Enabled,
            Last
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static void RemoveFromFlip3D(IntPtr Hwnd)
        {           
            int renderPolicy = (int)DwmNCRenderingPolicy.Enabled;
            DwmSetWindowAttribute(Hwnd, (int)DwmWindowAttribute.Flip3DPolicy, ref renderPolicy, sizeof(int));
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr AppHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            RemoveFromFlip3D(AppHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

It hides from Flip3D and the other ones remain as they were (alt-tab and taskbar). **However, the application remains showing in background while Flip3D is running**.

Answer (score 0):

Just set ShowInTaskbar for the main form to false:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfNoFlip3D.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Be aware that it doesn't work for Alt+Tab, it is only for Win+Tab (as per your request)
The side effect is that your application will also disappear from task bar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I want a solution to just remove from Flip3d not taskbar.