# Editing program to not show up when Alt-Tab

Tags: .net, alt-tab

Lately, I've been letting myself get annoyed by a program called SCM. It is a program that is necessary to make some of the buttons on my laptop work and it also works as a sort of quick settings overlay when you click on the icon in the notification area.

The problem with this program is that, whenever I Alt-Tab, it shows up in the dialog. If I try to Alt-Tab to it, nothing happens except that my previous window doesn't stay active. Basically, it's just there being useless.

I tried looking around for a way to hide programs from the Alt-Tab dialog and stumbled upon [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher), however my programming knowledge isn't great enough to know how to go about this. Especially, .NET and XAML are things I know nothing about.

How can I hide SCM from the Alt-Tab dialog?

Comment: This questions sounds like it's better suited for Super User

Comment: @PhilipPittle I was hesitating about that, but I decided to post here since I felt like I would have to mess with the code. Maybe I should post it in SuperUser after all.

Comment: This might help as well: http://superuser.com/questions/537722/alt-tab-box-displaying-hidden-programs-in-windows-8

Comment: @PhilipPittle Thanks, I looked at it before and tried it, but it didn't work. I don't think the person has the same problem as I.