# A window with no taskbar icon, no appearance in Alt-Tab and *without* using the ToolWindow extended style

Tags: wpf, winforms, taskbar, alt-tab, virtual-desktop

I have a problem that appears to be new to Windows 10.

I want to create a form that is visible to the user, but with no task bar icon and that does not appear in `Alt+Tab`.

This is perfectly doable if one is happy to sacrifice the normal styling of a window by following the [accepted solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher) for either WPF or Windows Forms.

The general advice for both WPF and Windows Forms is:

- Set `ShowInTaskbar` to `false`
- Enable the `ToolWindow` styling (either through setting the border style in WinForms or the `WindowStyle` in WPF)

However, this has a new, practical problem in Windows 10 when using [Virtual Desktops](https://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/04/16/virtual-desktops-in-windows-10-the-power-of-windowsmultiplied/): the moment you do the above, the WPF or WinForms window will appear in every virtual desktop. See my example application with a red background:

[image: window appears in every virtual desktop]

This affects both the `Task View` switching screen and the actual desktop itself. No matter where you go, the form is there!

Is there any way to show a form - or even just a bitmap - on Windows without anything appearing in the taskbar, without anything appearing in `Alt+Tab` *and* without duplicating the window on every virtual desktop?

I have spent two days researching every possible option, trying every example online, reading MSDN documentation on window styles etc. but all resort to the same method, either through P/Invoke calls or directly, but either way the result is the same.

Comment: Any luck on this one? We're experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I'm facing this exact problem now also... looks like there is not much hope