# Show application on taskbar but NOT in Alt+Tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

What I basically did was a program that shows CPU/RAM/Sound levels in taskbar [image]

but it also shows in the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> dialog
[image]

I have used this code snippet for hiding applications from the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
  get
  {
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;
    return cp;
   }
}
```

But that only works if `ShowInTaskbar` is set to `false` but I need it on because obvious reasons. Is there some way to make it not show in <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and still preserve itself in the taskbar?

Comment: That is probably impossible.

Comment: Actually, try making a tool window.

Comment: That still shows in alt+tab

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/357598/1038838)

Comment: @SLaks `cp.ExStyle |= 0x80` does make it a tool window. `0x80` is `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`

Comment: Maybe you need to create a [Desk Band](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx#desk_bands)?

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this thing..