# Remove the window from the taskbar in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, taskbar, winui-3

I'm creating an app that needs UI but not show up inside the taskbar, I know exactly how to do this in, winforms and wpf, but the window object doesn't contain a `ShowInTaskBar` variable that I can just change.

I have tried [NotifyIcon](https://github.com/HavenDV/H.NotifyIcon) but that doesn't hide it from the taskbar, I also can't find any documentation on if this is even possible.

I only create a stack overflow question when I've spent more than 5 hours on this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20of%20hiding%20a%20window,make%20it%20a%20child%20window%20of%20another%20window.

Comment: @Nick your link seems to be for WPF. I've just tried it for WinUI3 and `ShowInTaskbar` doesn't seem available on the `Window` control. (The OP already says that in the question)

Comment: @JHBonarius, you are not being careful. :-) Look at the solution which involves changing the style of the window.

Comment: "Careful"? I think something got lost in translation there. Anyhow, that question has many many answers, most of which don't apply to WinUI3, so it's a needle in a haystack. Please be specific.

Comment: @JHBonarius I applied it and it actually did work, I just had to add the window handle to in the win32 api and it worked.

Comment: @JHBonarius im using C# too?

Comment: ah, sorry, I'm not used to low-level WinRt access with c#. So misread this for C++. It's pretty ugly way of having to write code. Microsoft should definitely abstract is away... but WinUI3 has many issues like this in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is quite easy nowadays. Just type in the constructor of your window in code-behind:

```cs
public partial class YourWindow
{
  public YourWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AppWindow.IsShownInSwitchers = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383426/nick) showed me this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/551847/14724147

Just add the window handle to the win32 api and it will hide it from alt+tab and the taskbar

```cs
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
    int exStyle = (int)GetWindowLong(hWnd, (int)GetWindowLongFields.GWL_EXSTYLE);
    exStyle |= (int)ExtendedWindowStyles.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, (int)GetWindowLongFields.GWL_EXSTYLE, (IntPtr)exStyle);
}

#region Window styles
[Flags]
public enum ExtendedWindowStyles
{
    // ...
    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080,
    // ...
}

public enum GetWindowLongFields
{
    // ...
    GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20),
    // ...
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

public static IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
{
    int error = 0;
    IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
    // Win32 SetWindowLong doesn't clear error on success
    SetLastError(0);

    if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
    {
        // use SetWindowLong
        Int32 tempResult = IntSetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex, IntPtrToInt32(dwNewLong));
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        result = new IntPtr(tempResult);
    }
    else
    {
        // use SetWindowLongPtr
        result = IntSetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }

    if ((result == IntPtr.Zero) && (error != 0))
    {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(error);
    }

    return result;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr IntSetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Int32 IntSetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, Int32 dwNewLong);

private static int IntPtrToInt32(IntPtr intPtr)
{
    return unchecked((int)intPtr.ToInt64());
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLastError")]
public static extern void SetLastError(int dwErrorCode);
#endregion
```

Comment: you can use AppWindow.IsShownInSwitchers and dont need to use pinvoke

Answer (score -1):

I'm the author of H.NotifyIcon and I recently added extensions for the Window type - ShowInTaskbar and HideInTaskbar
You can use them to achieve the desired behavior.

I think you just needed to write about it in issues on GitHub

Comment: yes, recently. I posted this about 9 months ago so going to the issues on GitHub wouldn't have helped at all because the feature didn't exist back then