# How to hide Taskbar icon for .NET MAUI desktop application

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

I have created an MAUI app and I want to hide its icon from Taskbar:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do it?

I was searching for a solution in internet but without success. I expect to have a simple solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, they want to hide the **icon**, not the whole taskbar. I assume (and hope) this is impossible to do programmatically; it smells of malware. It is up to the user and the OS to control what is visible to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Maui for Windows is based on the WinUI 3, so I refer to this case about [Removing the window from the taskbar in WinUI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261765/remove-the-window-from-the-taskbar-in-winui-3). I have tested it and the icon will be hiden.

Add the method in the **/Platforms/Windows/App.cs**:

```
public partial class App : MauiWinUIApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Window styles
    [Flags]
    public enum ExtendedWindowStyles
    {
        // ...
        WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080,
        // ...
    }

    public enum GetWindowLongFields
    {
        // ...
        GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20),
        // ...
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    public static IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
    {
        int error = 0;
        IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
        // Win32 SetWindowLong doesn't clear error on success
        SetLastError(0);

        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            // use SetWindowLong
            Int32 tempResult = IntSetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex, IntPtrToInt32(dwNewLong));
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            result = new IntPtr(tempResult);
        }
        else
        {
            // use SetWindowLongPtr
            result = IntSetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }

        if ((result == IntPtr.Zero) && (error != 0))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(error);
        }

        return result;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr IntSetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern Int32 IntSetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, Int32 dwNewLong);

    private static int IntPtrToInt32(IntPtr intPtr)
    {
        return unchecked((int)intPtr.ToInt64());
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLastError")]
    public static extern void SetLastError(int dwErrorCode);
    #endregion

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}
```

And in the MainPage.cs:

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
        IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
        int exStyle = (int)GetWindowLong(hWnd, (int)GetWindowLongFields.GWL_EXSTYLE);
        exStyle |= (int)ExtendedWindowStyles.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, (int)GetWindowLongFields.GWL_EXSTYLE, (IntPtr)exStyle);
#endif
      }
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you mentioned above but, in the MainPage.cs UI is not found in Windows namespace, which package I need to install?

Comment: You don't have to install any package. Which api or method is not found? Can you show more details? The code I provided worked well in my project. Did you copy it? @BlerimSherifi

Comment: You can just copy my code to your project and you can use the fisrt content page in your project instead of the MainPage. @BlerimSherifi

Comment: I did that but, I am getting build errors.

Comment: Can you show the details such as the image or error message? @BlerimSherifi

Comment: It worked now, I had to include some references, thanks a lot.